# Adding ellipsis via css pseudo element "after"

Tags: css, unicode, escaping, html-entities

I am having difficulty adding an ellipsis after each of my h5 tags in a CSS style sheet:

```
h5::after{
    content:'&hellip;';
}
```

I know that CSS is not HTML and thus`&hellip;` will not work. I learned somewhere that I should use unicode characters. Whatever I try will not work. Here are some values that I have tried:

- `content:'&hellip;';` (produces 'h5 & h e l l i p;')
- `content:'2026';` (produces 'h52026')
- `content:'\2026';` (produces 'h5,6')
- `content:'\u2026';` (produces 'h5u2026')
- `content:'\u+2026';` (produces 'h5u+2026')
- `content:'\2026\0020';` (produces 'h5,60')

My CSS is prefixed with `@charset "UTF-8";`, and I'm wondering if this is part of the problem.

---

**Edit:** I fixed the issue, *though I do not know why my fix works.* **If you can let me know why, then the green check mark goes to you.** There are two versions of the fix. Both work.

Fix 1: Store the unicode value in a pre-processor variable (like: `$e = '\002026';`) and then output `content:'$e'`

Fix 2: Escape the backslash in the unicode: `content:'\\002026';`

Answer (score 2):

Try it like below:

```css
p:after {
 content:"\002026"
}
```

```html
<p>some text</p>
```

Comment: Results in "026".

Comment: what browser you're using? it works perfectly fine on Chrome (mac)

Comment: @AdamKosmala I have tested it in Chrome, Safari, and Blisk — same results everywhere. I am using a pre-processor (PHP) and right now, I'm wondering if there is an issue there.

Comment: Unless you're processing CSS anyhow, that wouldn't make any difference. I tested it also on Chrome on Windows and it looks fine to me

Comment: @AdamKosmala I worked it out, though I don't know the reasoning. Please see my edit in the OP. Do you have any thoughts on this fix?

Comment: well, without having possibility to see the version before the fix of yours and 'standard' version, I can't say what was the root cause, but I'm glad you worked it out ;)